# Using ClosedXML how to adjust image size according row height

Tags: c#, closedxml

I set a row height. After that I place picture in first cell. How can I adjust image size according row height?

```
worksheet.Row(1).Height = 265;
var image = worksheet.AddPicture(imagePath).MoveTo(worksheet.Cell("A1"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `worksheet.Row(1).Height = 265` statement just changes the height of the *row*. If you want to change the height of the *image*, use something like:

```
var image = worksheet.AddPicture(imagePath).MoveTo(worksheet.Cell("A1")).WithSize(265, 265);
```

Answer (score 2):

To retain proportions of the image you can use Scale method

```
        ws.Row(1).Height = 300;
        var pic = ws.AddPicture(imageFile, "Logo").MoveTo(ws.Cell(1, 1));            
        pic.Scale( ws.Row(1).Height / (pic.OriginalHeight * 0.75d));
```